# jQuery select data from row onChange to option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created Admin page which displays all users details from Database.
The table is populated using Spring + Hibernate. 
I made attempt to select value of option menu but I have no idea how to select username of a given row.

Later I want to make a call to Controller to change the user role.

```
<div class="list">
    <table class="table-list">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>Change role</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="users" items="${users}">
            <tr class="userdetails">
                <td><c:out value="${users.id }" /></td>
                <td class="username"><c:out value="${users.username }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${users.password }" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${users.email }" /></td>
                <c:forEach var="roles" items="${users.usersRoles }">
                    <td><c:out value="${roles.role }" /></td>
                </c:forEach>
                <td><select id="change-role"><c:forEach var='changeRole'
                            items='${roles}'>

                            <option value="${changeRole.role}"><c:out
                                    value='${changeRole.role}' /></option>

                        </c:forEach></select></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if i understood you right, you want to update the role of a user, when it gets selected in the select control? Or do you also want to change the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using HTML5 data- attribute to your select option like

```
<select id="change-role">
   <c:forEach var='changeRole' items='${roles}'>
      <option value="${changeRole.role}" data-userid="${users.id }" data-username="${users.username }">
       <c:out value='${changeRole.role}' />
       </option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

And in the change event of your Select use jquery/javascript code to fetch username and userid of selected row

```
$('#change-role').change(function(e){
  var userid=$(this).find('option:selected').data('userid');
  var username=$(this).find('option:selected').data('username');

  //You code to use Userid and Username

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know what was wrong. Setting the ID which must be unique. Stupid me!
Everything works fine.